# how to get the key from json object and convert into an array?

Tags: c#, .net, json

```
{
 "Date": "2016-12-15",
 "Data": {
   "A": 4.4023,
   "AB": 1.6403,
   "ABC": 2.3457
 }
}
```

how can i get my keys A,Ab,ABC into an array? just the keys not value.

Comment: Deserialize it?  Parse it?

Comment: Using JavaScript : https://jsfiddle.net/n73zmLs0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) and use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to query the properties:

```
var jsonString = @"{
     ""Date"": ""2016-12-15"",
     ""Data"": {
       ""A"": 4.4023,
       ""AB"": 1.6403,
       ""ABC"": 2.3457
     }
}";

var root = JToken.Parse(jsonString);

var properties = root
    // Select nested Data object
    .SelectTokens("Data")
    // Iterate through its children, return property names.
    .SelectMany(t => t.Children().OfType<JProperty>().Select(p => p.Name))
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", properties)); // Prints A,AB,ABC
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TJ06yC).