# How to get Key from nested object with a Json Object and return in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, key

I have a Json object which returns json.

I call an api and convert into json object:

```
var returnJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(removeChar, targetType: null);
```

The results are:

```
{
  "Type": "Local",
  "results": {
    "A": 4.4023,
    "B": 1.6403,
    "C": 2.3457
}
```

how do I do literate through this json object and return just keys in array?

I unsure what goes in foreach loop:

```
foreach(var item in returnJson)
{
//get just keys.ToArray();
}
```

class file

```
public class BasicResults
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public  Result results { get; set; }
    }

 public class Result
    {
      public double A { get; set; }
      public double B { get; set; }
      public double C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think this is in the right direction but can not target nested rate:

```
object[] getResults = returnJson.GetType()
                         .GetProperties()
                         .Select(p =>
                         {
                             object value = p.GetValue(results);
                             return value == null ? null : value.ToString();
                         })
                         .ToArray();
```

Comment: Do you want to get the A,B,C in your example?

Comment: yes please, just those values. Ideally returned in an array?

Comment: Seems very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171017/how-to-get-the-key-from-json-object-and-convert-into-an-array) that was asked 4 hours earlier.

Comment: What is in removeChar? I use the json string you put

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like below

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Results { get; set; }
}
```

And the do the Deserialize

```
var returnJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JsonData>(yourJsonString);
```

Then you can get the keys

```
 var keys = returnJson .Results.Keys;
```

Comment: could you give an example of how to implement?

Comment: var returnJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JsonData>(yourJsonString); doesn't work I need to use var returnJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(removeChar, targetType: null);

Comment: I will update question as class already set.