# How do I get and return a key value from a complex json object?

Tags: c#, json, discord

I have a discord bot that can get a key from a JSON file and return the value depending on the command a user inputs. I want to be able to access complex JSON keys (like "charQuote") and return the associative value (which would be "Video Game character quote here").

```
{
"characterKey": 
{
"charName":"Video Game character name here",
"charQuote": "Video Game character quote here", 
"charImageURL": "Video Game character image url here"
}

//I omitted 11 other complex objects that are similar to this one
}
```

Other answers like:

[How do I deserialize a complex JSON object in C# .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339167/how-do-i-deserialize-a-complex-json-object-in-c-sharp-net)

[How to get Key from nested object with a Json Object and return in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174082/how-to-get-key-from-nested-object-with-a-json-object-and-return-in-array)

[how to get the key from json object and convert into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171017/how-to-get-the-key-from-json-object-and-convert-into-an-array)

...deserialize and return the complex objects and/or keys as an array. But I want to return a single key value from one complex object.

Here, I have a class that manages a separate JSON file with simple JSON objects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace discordbot.Modules
{
    class Utilities
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> alerts;
        private const string File_Path = "json files/alerts.json";

        static Utilities()
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(File_Path);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            alerts = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();          
        }

        public static string GetAlert(string key) //"hello" == key
        {
            if (alerts.ContainsKey(key))
                return alerts[key]; //returns "Hello World" which is the value
            return "";
        }
```

This class returns the value from the inputted key. An example asynchronous task method that would use this class would be:

```
[Command("test")]
        public async Task HelloWorldAsync(string hello = "hello")
        {
            await ReplyAsync(Utilities.GetAlert(hello));
        }
```

And here's the class that associates with the JSON file that contains complex objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace discordbot.Modules
{
    public static class CharacterUtilities 
    {

        //private static List<Dictionary<string, string>> QuoteAndPicture = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        private static Dictionary<string, string> QuoteAndPicture = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        private const string File_Path = "json files/quotesandimages.json";

        static CharacterUtilities()
        {
            if(!File.Exists(File_Path))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(File_Path, "");
            }

            string json = File.ReadAllText(File_Path); 
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            QuoteAndPicture = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        }

        public static string GetQuoteImageName(string key) 
        {                        
            if (QuoteAndPicture.ContainsKey(key)))
                return QuoteAndPicture[key];
            return "";
        }
```

Asynchronous method to invoke `GetQuoteImageName`

```
[Command("ex")] [RequireOwner]
        public async Task CharacterAsync(string characterContext)
        {                   
            await ReplyAsync(CharacterUtilities.GetQuoteImageName(characterContext)); 
        }
```

As it is right now, if I invoke the `GetQuoteImageName` method, I get the error: `The type initializer for 'discordbot.Modules.CharacterUtilities' threw an exception.`

So I'm wondering if there's a similar way to return a singular value from a complex object instead of all the complex values, similar to the first class above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search through the json based on the `keysToSearchThrough`.

```
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
        // The keys you have to search through.
        string[] keysToSearchThrough = new string[] { "characterKey", "charName" };

        string result = string.Empty;

        // The current data it is travesing through
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> currTraversedData = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < keysToSearchThrough.Length; ++i) {

            if (currTraversedData.ContainsKey(keysToSearchThrough[i])) {
                // Get the value if the key current exists
                dynamic currTravesedDataValue = currTraversedData[keysToSearchThrough[i]];

                // Check if this 'currTravesedDataValue' can be converted to a 'Dictionary<string, dynamic>'
                if (IsStringDynamicDictionary(currTravesedDataValue)) {
                    // There is still more to travese through
                    currTraversedData = currTravesedDataValue.ToObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();
                } else {
                    // There is no more to travese through. (This is the result)
                    result = currTravesedDataValue.ToString();

                    // TODO: Some error checking in the event that we reached the result early, even though we still have more keys to travase through
                    break;
                }

            } else {
                // One of the keys to search through was probably invalid.
            }
        }

        // ...

        bool IsStringDynamicDictionary(dynamic input) {
            try {
                input.ToObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This initially converts the json data to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

> The reason why we have `dynamic` behind is because the `Value` can either be `string` or `Dictionary<string, string>` at any given point in time.

We then loop through the `keysToSearchThrough`, checking if the key exists in the current traversed dictionary.

If the key does exists, we then check if the Value of the current traversed dictionary is of Type `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

If it is, that means that we would have more to traverse through.
If not, it means that we probably reached the end.

> Example
>  
>   In `"charName":"Character name"`, the `Value` is a type of `String`. Which marks that we reached the end.
>   In `"charName": "Character name", "charQuote": "Character Quote"`, the `Value` would be a type of `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`. Which marks that we can still traverse through the data.

If it isn't obvious enough, the major downside is this code looks really messy.

Comment: Since I'll have 11 other complex objects, wouldn't I have to create 11 classes just for all of them?

Comment: @UchennaOnuigbo Sorry, I didn't originally get what you meant. I edited my answer to suit your question. Hope it helps